# Check if the given set is a subspace or not (set of non-invertible matrices, space solution of a system of homogeneous linear equations)

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you give me any hint in proving that these are subspaces?

1. The set of matrices of order $3x3$ such that the determinant equals $0$

I tried viewing the set as one of non-invertible matrices of order 3, but I don't know how to prove the closure.

2. The solution space of a system of homogeneous linear equations

No idea in this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Good find on #1! As for #2: what conditions do you have to check to verify that a subset of a vector space is a subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first one a counterexample could be made by finding two non-invertible matrices that when added give an invertible matrix.

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}+
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

The second one is a subspace, make a generalization of a system of homogeneous linear equations by creating one with m equations and n unknowns,
then simply verify the closure for addition and scalar multiplication (Because you can have two possible solutions either the trivial or infinite solutions to the system). You will find that the set of solutions to the system is a subspace of $R^n$